# Why string Method(Object object) may not match Func<Object, string> delegate type?

Tags: c#, delegates, type-conversion, func, method-call

I am writing a simple console-based menu system as a part of the course project in C#, where each item of the menu consists of a string to match user input and a command to execute.

```
public class MenuItem
    {
        private string _description;

        public string Description
        {
            get => _description;
            set => _description = Validate(value, 1, 100, false);
        }

        public Func<string> CommandToExecute { get; set; } // works

        public Func<Game, string> SaveCommand { get; set; } // refuses to work

    }
```

I have tried to use `Func<string>` to template static string methods, and it worked perfectly. However, now I need another Func to match a method taking a Game object as an input parameter and returning a string.

Unfortunately, when I tried to use `Func<Game, string> SaveCommand` to match my method `static string SaveGame(Game game)`, the program marked it as an error.

```
static string SaveGame(Game game)
        {
            var gameName = Console.ReadLine();

            ...
            return gameName;
        }
```

I am calling this method as following:

```
static string GameRun()
        {
            var game = new Game(_settings);

            var gameInnerMenu = new Menu(0)
                {
                    MenuTitle = "Choose one of the following actions:",
                    MenuItemsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, MenuItem>()
                    {
                        {
                            "S", new MenuItem()
                            {
                                Description = "Save the current game",
                                CommandToExecute = SaveGame(game)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
```

This code gives me an error `Cannot convert source type 'string' to target type 'System.Func<GameEngine.Game, string>'`.

I am very new to C# and OOP in general, so I would appreciate any suggestions on what can cause it and how it can be fixed.

Comment: when you create new Menu(0), use  CommandToExecute = SaveGame    (do not pass parameter game now , you just assign the method.., When you will use it, you will use menu.xxx.CommandToExecute(game)

Comment: Ahaa, that explains the error, thanks! But how can the call be tied to the menu in this case? Because currently I am matching the user input to the dictionary and executing the corresponding command via running the menu.

Comment: I don't know the whole logic of your program, but, I imagine you use "gameInnerMenu" 1) to display the menu's content... 
2) in your main loop or introduction state loop (or wathever), you have a listener or keyboard handler, and when you catch a 'S' key, you search in your gameInnerMenu   the entry 'S' and call the method attached. And this time with the Game parameter. ie : GameMenuItem gm=searchKey("S");  gm.CommandToExecute(game).  and CommandToExecute is a delegate to ... SaveGame. For the key "Q", you will have a CommandToExecute with a delegate to QuitGame methode, etc...

Comment: Thank you a lot! I have finally understood, that I was just overcomplicating my task, but it was really helpful to understand, what exactly was going on there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not assigning the `SaveGame` method to the `CommandToExecute` property. By using `CommandToExecute = SaveGame(game)` you are instead executing the `SaveGame` method and assign the return value to `CommandToExecute`.

What you should do is

```
{
    ...
    CommandToExecute = SaveGame
}
```

---

If you want to look it up, this syntax is called method group conversion, and it's a shortcut for writing `CommandToExecute = new Func<Game, string>(SaveGame)`.